Tree that spills blood when sawed
I recently recalled a movie I've seen when I was little, and it was pretty creepy. However, I can't remember much of it except for a single scene: A guy with a chainsaw trying to cut down a tree and suddenly a lot of blood spills from it! I remember that tree as being part of the main plot, as it seemed to be cursed or something.
I also remember a bit of the scenario, which seems to show mostly the courtyard, and the house has a white door. If I remember well, a woman is killed inside the house, falling over the same door. There are children shown in this movie as well, as part of the family.
I can't recall the rest for sure, I was really little and couldn't recall more than that. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance. 

When you were "little" only helps if we know your age. Can you give us a time-frame for the movie? 70s? 80s?

Sorry, I forgot to mention that, I watched it sometime between 1994 and 1996.

This might be 1990's The Guardian. From the Wikipedia page 

The opening cards explain that ancient druids worshiped trees,
  sometimes offering them human sacrifices. Some of these trees were
  connected with evil.

The main plot concerns a family who hires a nanny only to find that she's trying to abduct their son. Near the end of the movie, the father takes a chainsaw to one of the trees and the tree bleeds on being cut. The entire movie is available on Youtube

Thank you very much for your answer, I'm going to check. ^^

That was exactly it. Funny how what I remember was actually the ending of the film, thought I had stopped watching the movie after that scene out of fear. Thank you so much. :)
